# How to set horizontal and vertical heading along with MS Chart X axis and Y axis?

Tags: c#, .net, window, bar-chart, mschart

I am working on chart control in c# .Net - windows application, It is easy to use but a bit tough to customize or doing formatting is a bit tedious.

I am done with chart, but i want to show horizontal and vertical arrow line along with some text in it, i am posting an image for example:

[image]

Please let me know if chart control has some property for this. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Finally found the way of showing this:

```
 chart1.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisX.Title = "Test Number sorted by Date";
 chart1.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisX.TitleFont = new Font("Sans Serif", 10, FontStyle.Bold);
 chart1.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisY.Title = "Percentage Obtained";
 chart1.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisY.TitleFont = new Font("Sans Serif", 10, FontStyle.Bold);
```

now chart looks like:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Even Below code works.check this out
    `<ChartAreas> 
    <asp:ChartArea Name="ChartArea1">
    <AxisX Title="Test Number Sorted By Date"></AxisX>
    <AxisY Title="Percentage Obtained"></AxisY>
    </asp:ChartArea>
    </ChartAreas>`